# no error raised by compiler but not getting the correct answer in character occurrence program

Tags: java, netbeans

```
String s1=t1.getText();
char ch=t2.getText().charAt(0);
int a=0; 
 int i=0;

for(i=0;i<s1.length();i++)
{
if(s1.charAt(i)==ch)
    a++;
}t3.setText(""+a);
```

this is my code where t1,t2,t2 are textfields. The compiler doesn't raises any error but i am repeatedly getting 1 as a result no matter whatever character at whatever place i use. PLEASE HELP!!!

Comment: in `ch` you need a char which exists in `s1` String.

Comment: sorry. i didn't get what were you trying to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String s1="hello world";
char ch= 'o';
int a=0; 

for(int i=0;i<s1.length();i++){
    if(s1.charAt(i)==ch){
        a++;
    }
}

System.out.println(""+a);
```

Works perfectly. However, if you do not provide a character that exists in `s1`you will not get a result.

Comment: sir we are unaware what will be in s1 and the same for ch ie. we have to receive that input from the user how are we gonna do that?

Comment: As you did, I suppose - I just modified your code to a minimal working example.

Comment: sorry for all the trouble finally i got that you are correct i was wrong with the interpretation of the program i took the program as one which is counting where the char was occurring but what i made is one that counts the repetition of the given char. sorry.